# SELECTING columns and matching rows

Tags: mysql, join

Got a small problem regarding selecting data in my MySQL table. I got 2 tables.

```
questions_table
- id
- name

results_table
- id
- form_id
- answer 1
- etc.
```

Now I want to select all the forms which has results, and the form_id matches the form id, because that is how they are linked.

I got this:

```
select f.id, f.name, count(res.id) from forms f LEFT JOIN results res ON f.id = res.form_id
```

But the problem is, I only get 1 row out of it, while I have multiple forms with multiple results, but it only selects the one form.

What am i doing wrong? Is it the LEFT JOIN statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate function without `group by` will always returns one row. You need to add `group by`

```
select 
f.id, 
f.name, 
count(res.id) 
from forms f LEFT JOIN results res ON f.id = res.form_id 
group by f.id
```

Comment: Thanks this is the answer, I'll mark it as answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all the forms which has results

Try this: (edited: count added)

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, count(res.form_id) AS cnt
FROM forms AS f
LEFT JOIN results AS res ON f.id = res.form_id
WHERE res.form_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY f.id
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer to my question, only you don't have count in the query! Thanks for the answer!